# Can we make a symmetric wavefunction out of two anti-symmetric wavefunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, bosons

And, if so, then can be say that we've made a boson out of two fermions?

Mathematically,

If

f=fermion=f(x,y)

then

b=boson=[f(x,y)-f(y,x)]/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the product of two antisymmetric wavefunctions is symmetric. However, such a system is not a fundamental particle, it is a composite system (of an even number of fermions).

Such systems do exist: they are called [composite bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_boson) (in order to distinguish them from [elementary bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_particles#Bosons) like the photon or the Higgs boson). Examples include [Cooper pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair) in superconductors, and [superfluid Helium-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4), a Bose-Einstein Condensate.

Comment: That's interesting. Because the spin of two fermions add to 1 and two fermions also make a boson. So does this kinda sorta almost prove the spin statistics theorem?